# How to load SFrame directory archive data into Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, sframe

I am doing a Machine Learning Course on coursera and I am unable to load the data required for the assignment. I was supposed to download the zip file and use it on jupyter notebook. I gather it is a SFRAME directory archive.

```
sf = SFrame(data = "C:\Users\tipl jmmipl\Downloads\data for sfrme.zip")
```

this is the format of the data

```
PK
N��N
people_wiki.sframe/UX ...
�0D�9L�1�1��n��D$ԤL�|
m=~Mw�j�y��|�����2�9 ...
I@<O\t
__MACOSX/UX\x0c�u�] ...
�Aưrj���#=�;�K@��
�Y�;�G�A����N���r�=� ...
�f
�f�\t�P���M�T�ɞ��M|�
�\x0bA�a ...
��/�P�!��\>g�K靡���DZ`
��W��W)���_�}���T��^ ...
�U€ᕼ;E�-���m�o������N
��f4��9e��?f;#y��E�J ...
���I��p1�O��9Fv�`�
�֫VS^����?�����?H�F ...
l�?A���
��T��9f!I�_����';�G ...
[131851 rows x 1 columns]
Note: Only the head of the SFrame is printed.
You can use print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n) to print more rows and columns.
```

How do i load this data on jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported `turicreate`?
After importing turicreate you should do `sf = tc.SFrame('fileDirectory')`. I have imported `turicreate` as `tc`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the zipped file, unzip file at your local directory. Create a new folder at jupyter notebook with "name.sframe" then copy all file from the folder which you unzip before. Then just code as normal:
`import turicreate as tc`
`sf = tc.load_sframe('name.sframe')`